# Django views and urls - can't runserver

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm learning django and having issues with implementing this code below:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('members/', views.members, name='members'),
]
```

The code above is stored in a urls.py file I created in an app folder as directed  by the tutorial guide. However when I try to run it on the browser I get this message:

The included URLconf '<module 'members.urls' from 'C:\Users\Chinasaokwu\Desktop\storefront\try-django\my_app\members\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

I don't know what to do here. I'm new to django.

It's w3schools.com that I am using as a guide

I'm still learning how views and urls work since I'm new to django but I understand that views are functions that take and return https requests/response, and that urls are used to implement views.

Comment: Totally sure that the error is related to either circular import in another file or you missed url patterns in some apps' urls.py but the error is not due to that urls.py code, you shared in question.

Comment: Show your project's urls.py.